# How do I filter on date in Play-SLICK which is saved as Instant?

Tags: postgresql, scala, playframework, slick

I am using `scala`, `play`, `sclick`; and `postgres`. I have made a table named `order` & it contains a field named `created` in timestamp format with zone. Now I would like to search on `order` based on `created` with parameters `year` & `month` as follows:-

```
SELECT * FROM   "order"
WHERE  created::text LIKE '2016-07%';
```

The above query works fine in postgres.

---

The scala code I have written for `Order` is:-

```
case class Order(id: Option[Int],
                 customerId: Int,
                 amount: Double,
                 created: Option[Instant],
                 updated: Option[Instant]) extends GenericEntity {
        def this(customerId: Int,
                 amount: Double,) = this(None, customerId, amount, None, None)
}

class OrderTable(tag: Tag) extends GenericTable[Order](tag, "order") {
        override def id = column[Option[Int]]("id", O.PrimaryKey, O.AutoInc)    
        def customerId = column[Int]("customer_id")
        def amount = column[Dount]("amount")

        def customer = foreignKey("fk_order_customer", customerId, Customers.table)(_.id.getOrElse(1), onUpdate = ForeignKeyAction.Restrict, onDelete = ForeignKeyAction.Cascade)

        def * = (id, customerId, amount, created, updated) <> ((Order.apply _).tupled, Order.unapply)
}

object Orders extends GenericService[Order, OrderTable] {
        override val table = TableQuery[OrderTable]

        override def copyEntityFields(entity: Order, id: Option[Int], created: Option[Instant], updated: Option[Instant]): Order = {
          entity.copy(id = id, created = created, updated = updated)
        }

        def getMonthlyOrder(year:Int, month: Int) = {
          // execute LIKE query for the following query
          // SELECT * FROM   "order"
          // WHERE  created::text LIKE '2016-07%';
        }    
}
```

Where `GenericEntity` defines `id`, `created`, `updated`.

---

So what code should I write for `getMonthlyOrder` function with `year` and `month`?.

Comment: Did you try https://github.com/tminglei/slick-pg?

Answer (score 1):

You need two things:

1) A column type to let Slick know how to persist Instant to database. In this case you want to map Instant to java.sql.Timestamp, which Slick can use natively.

```
implicit val instantColumnType: BaseColumnType[Instant] =
    MappedColumnType.base[Instant, Timestamp](
        instant => Timestamp.from(instant),
        ts => ts.toInstant
    )
```

2) Functions to extract year and month from your timestamp. Here I used another approach than your LIKE query. You could also define a mapping from Instant to String and use something like startsWith.

```
val yearFn = SimpleFunction.unary[Instant, Int]("year")
val monthFn = SimpleFunction.unary[Instant, Int]("month")
```

Then you would use them in getMonthlyOrder like this

```
def getMonthlyOrder(year: Int, month: Int): Future[Seq[Order]] = {
    val query = table.filter(_.created.map((created) => yearFn(created) === year && monthFn(created) === month))
    db.run(query.result)
}
```

The complete code valid for Slick 3.1:

```
import java.sql.Timestamp
import java.time.Instant
import javax.inject.{Inject, Singleton}

import play.api.db.slick.{DatabaseConfigProvider, HasDatabaseConfigProvider}
import slick.driver.JdbcProfile
import slick.lifted.TableQuery

import scala.concurrent.Future

case class Order(id: Int,
                 customerId: Int,
                 amount: Double,
                 created: Option[Instant],
                 updated: Option[Instant])
@Singleton
class Orders @Inject()(val dbConfigProvider: DatabaseConfigProvider) extends HasDatabaseConfigProvider[JdbcProfile] {
    val table = TableQuery[OrderTable]

    import driver.api._

    implicit val instantColumnType: BaseColumnType[Instant] =
        MappedColumnType.base[Instant, Timestamp](
            instant => Timestamp.from(instant),
            ts => ts.toInstant
        )

    val yearFn = SimpleFunction.unary[Instant, Int]("year")
    val monthFn = SimpleFunction.unary[Instant, Int]("month")

    def getMonthlyOrder(year: Int, month: Int): Future[Seq[Order]] = {
        val query = table.filter(_.created.map((created) => yearFn(created) === year && monthFn(created) === month))
        db.run(query.result)
    }

    class OrderTable(tag: Tag) extends Table[Order](tag, "ORDERS") {

        def * = (id, customerId, amount, created, updated) <> ((Order.apply _).tupled, Order.unapply)

        def id = column[Int]("ID", O.PrimaryKey, O.AutoInc)

        def customerId = column[Int]("CUSTOMER_ID")

        def amount = column[Double]("AMOUNT")

        def created = column[Option[Instant]]("CREATED")

        def updated = column[Option[Instant]]("UPDATED")
    }

}
```

Comment: Hello, if the instant is generated from a ZonedDateTime(eg: `ZonedDateTime.ofInstant(myDateVar, UTC)`), won't converting the Instant to `java.sql.Timestamp` loose the millisecond information Or does it happen when we want to go from Timestamp -> Instant?